# How to specify a generic type for a function parameter

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to define a function that takes a parameter of a generic type in Postgresql? So for example if I wanted to define a function where the argument could be either numeric or character varying:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION toStr(col ??Generic Type??)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
select 
case when pg_typeof(col) = 'character varying'::regtype then col::'character varying'
case when pg_typeof(col) = 'numeric'::regtype then to_char(col::numeric, '999')
  else 'Unsupported type'
$BODY$
```

So if this is possible what would my ??Generic Type?? be?

Comment: `anyelement` as type.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `anyelement` [pseudo type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-pseudo.html) which accepts any data type;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION toStr(col anyelement)
  RETURNS character varying 
AS $$
select 
case when pg_typeof(col) = 'character varying'::regtype then (col::character varying)
     when pg_typeof(col) = 'numeric'::regtype then to_char(col::numeric, '999')
  else 'Unsupported type' end
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

[An SQLfiddle showing it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e86e/1).